# Grafana NGINX reverse proxy not functioning correctly

Tags: monitoring, nginx, grafana

I seem to be having trouble with Grafana behind an nginx proxy. I'm getting console errors and errors in Grafana, and the changes I try to make in Grafana are not working.

Errors:
From within Grafana I get "Origin not allowed" when trying to access the site from https://grafana.domainname.dev and making any action.

I see console errors of

this kind whenenver i load a page:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 4030(forbidden) URL: https://grafana.domainname.dev/public/fonts/roboto/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUVtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 4030(forbidden) URL: https://grafana.domainname.dev/public/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0

this kind whenever i go into submenus or try to make changes (these two errors occur the same time as origin not allowed error)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 4030(forbidden) URL: https://grafana.domainname.dev/api/frontend-metrics

Uncaught (in promise)

```
{
    "status": 403,
    "statusText": "Forbidden",
    "data": {
        "message": "origin not allowed\n",
        "error": "Forbidden",
        "response": "origin not allowed\n"
    },
    "config": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "api/frontend-metrics",
        "data": {
            "events": [
                {
                    "name": "frontend_boot_first-paint_time_seconds",
                    "value": 1.045
                },
                {
                    "name": "frontend_boot_first-contentful-paint_time_seconds",
                    "value": 1.045
                },
                {
                    "name": "frontend_boot_load_time_seconds",
                    "value": 1.311
                }
            ]
        },
        "retry": 0,
        "headers": {
            "X-Grafana-Org-Id": 1
        },
        "hideFromInspector": true
    }
}
```

Grafana Config:

General Configuration:

```
instance_name = grafana.domainname.dev

Server block: 
[server]
# Protocol (http, https, h2, socket)
;protocol = http

# The ip address to bind to, empty will bind to all interfaces
;http_addr =

# The http port  to use
;http_port = 3000

# The public facing domain name used to access grafana from a browser
domain = grafana.domainname.dev

# Redirect to correct domain if host header does not match domain
# Prevents DNS rebinding attacks
;enforce_domain = true

# The full public facing url you use in browser, used for redirects and emails
# If you use reverse proxy and sub path specify full url (with sub path)
root_url = https://grafana.domainname.dev/

# Serve Grafana from subpath specified in `root_url` setting. By default it is set to `false` for compatibility reasons.
;serve_from_sub_path = false
```

Everything else is unaltered, except for mail settings I set further down. When i try to turn on enforce_domain it ends up in a redirect loop and the browser can't connect.

NGINX Config:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/grafana.domainname.dev :

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

server {

        root /var/www/grafana/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name grafana.domainname.dev www.grafana.domainname.dev;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }

        location /api/live {
          rewrite  ^/(.*)  /$1 break;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }




    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/grafana.domainname.dev/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/grafana.domainname.dev/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = grafana.domainname.dev) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name grafana.domainname.dev www.grafana.domainname.dev;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Some of the above was added by certbot, and I didn't touch any of that, and I tried to follow grafana's tutorial as well as some forum suggestions but to no avail!

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
         default upgrade;
         '' close;
        }


        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This is all standard except I did add the map $http_upgrade part however that doesn't look to have done anything.

If anyone has any insight here, I'd really appreciate it! It looks like something isn't making it back to localhost:3000 however I'm not sure why/how that is possible when nginx is configured to send everything from grafana.domainname.dev to localhost:3000. Appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `Host` header needs to be preserved now.

For nginx: `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` in BOTH your Location blocks.

For Apache2: `ProxyPreserveHost On` [1]

[1] https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/45117#issuecomment-1033842787